# Sencha Touch Cordova app build issues

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I create an application using

```
sencha generate app SenchaTest C:\users\username\deskop\SenchaTest
```

From there I initialize cordova using

```
sencha cordova init
```

It appears up until here everything is fine.

I edit app.jason to include

```
"platforms": "android",
```

in the build section

I then run

```
sencha app build native
```

To build the cordova application

It results in this error near the end of the commands output

```
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mferreira\Desktop\SenchaTest\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:286: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mferreira\Desktop\SenchaTest\.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:299: The followi
ng error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mferreira\Desktop\SenchaTest\.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:305: Problem: fa
iled to create task or type x-compass-compile
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I do have compass installed, it's a totally fresh app so it can't be an issue with my version of sencha cmd. Totally at a loss as to how to fix this. No idea how to even get started with packaging this thing for android/windows development

I assume I'm supposed to have a build generated in the cordova\platforms directory and that to build for windows I'd just include windows in the "Platforms" within the app.json.

Comment: Do you have ant installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you installed Sencha CMD with the Compass option checked? I had the same issue and this little thing worked for me.